# Why return nil tableViewCell for UITableViewDiffableDataSource cellProvider param?

Tags: swift, ios13

**iOS** **13** has some new *API* for handling `tableView` and one interesting area of the *API* is the `cell` provider **parameter** of `UITableViewDiffableDataSource`

```
public typealias CellProvider = (UITableView, IndexPath, ItemIdentifierType) -> UITableViewCell?
```

When would it be appropriate to **return** a `nil` `UITableViewCell` here ?

Answer (score 3):

So this API is still in beta which means the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdiffabledatasource/cellprovider?changes=l_5) isn't complete.

It states:

> This documentation contains preliminary information about an API or technology in development. This information is subject to change, and software implemented according to this documentation should be tested with final operating system software.

**TLDR - As of right now if you create a `UITableView` and use a `UITableViewDiffableDataSource` that returns nil your app will crash.**

However, [this](https://www.wwdcbysundell.com/2019/diffable-data-sources-first-look/) blog post goes over some of the new details. It doesn't mention anything about returning nil for a cell though.

You can also take a look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/220/) WWDC session. Around the 15 minute mark you can see that the sample code throws a fatal error if the cell cannot be created.

Using the blog above I made a simple tableView in Xcode 11 like this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    enum Section: CaseIterable {
        case friends
        case family
        case coworkers
    }

    struct Contact: Hashable {
        var name: String
        var email: String
    }

    struct ContactList {
        var friends: [Contact]
        var family: [Contact]
        var coworkers: [Contact]
    }

    private let tableView = UITableView()
    private let cellReuseIdentifier = "cell"
    private lazy var dataSource = makeDataSource()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self,
                           forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier
        )

        tableView.dataSource = dataSource

        view.addSubview(tableView)

        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        loadData()
    }


    func makeDataSource() -> UITableViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Contact> {
        let reuseIdentifier = cellReuseIdentifier

        return UITableViewDiffableDataSource(
            tableView: tableView,
            cellProvider: {  tableView, indexPath, contact in
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
                    withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier,
                    for: indexPath
                )

                cell.textLabel?.text = contact.name
                cell.detailTextLabel?.text = contact.email
                return cell
            }
        )
    }

    func update(with list: ContactList, animate: Bool = true) {
        let snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Contact>()
        snapshot.appendSections(Section.allCases)

        snapshot.appendItems(list.friends, toSection: .friends)
        snapshot.appendItems(list.family, toSection: .family)
        snapshot.appendItems(list.coworkers, toSection: .coworkers)

        dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: animate)
    }

    func loadData() {
        let friends = [
            Contact(name: "Bob", email: "Bob@gmail.com"),
            Contact(name: "Tom", email: "Tom@myspace.com")
        ]

        let family = [
            Contact(name: "Mom", email: "mom@aol.com"),
            Contact(name: "Dad", email: "dad@aol.com")
        ]

        let coworkers = [
            Contact(name: "Mason", email: "tim@something.com"),
            Contact(name: "Tim", email: "mason@something.com")
        ]

        let contactList = ContactList(friends: friends, family: family, coworkers: coworkers)
        update(with: contactList, animate: true)
    }
}
```

Everything loads up fine, so I decided to see what would happen if I return nil for a cell so I added this code in `UITableViewDiffableDataSource`:

```
if contact.name == "Bob" {
    return nil
}
```

This ended up causing a crash:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource returned a nil cell for row at index path: <NSIndexPath: 0xd6d99b18b93a5a0e> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}. Table view: <UITableView: 0x7f8d30006200; frame = (-207 -448; 414 896); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60000239de00>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600002dd0ec0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {414, 264}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}; dataSource: <_TtGC5UIKit29UITableViewDiffableDataSourceOC5iOS1314ViewController7SectionVS2_7Contact_: 0x600002ffc520>>, dataSource: <_TtGC5UIKit29UITableViewDiffableDataSourceOC5iOS1314ViewController7SectionVS2_7Contact_: 0x600002ffc520>'
```

In fact just returning nil (no cell at all) also causes a crash as soon as the datasource applies the update. So as of right now as far as I can tell returning nil isn't a real option since it causes a crash.

You can checkout the [full project](https://github.com/dtroupe18/UITableViewDiffableDataSourceExample) on github.

Comment: Sorry, just to be clear. Looking at my question, which is 'why return nil'. Your answer is 'I don't know'. ?

Comment: I updated my answer to be more clear. It's not really that "I don't know" it's more that there is no documentation and based on the sample code I provided returning `nil` causes the app to crash. You want to know why return nil? You want a crash.